# Does voltage rating increase on ceramic capacitors have any effect on the performance of the capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, ceramic

If I have a circuit that is designed for a ceramic, SMD, 0402, 1uF, 10%, 10V rated capacitor, and I swap in a ceramic, SMD, 0402, 1uF, 10%, 25V capacitor would anything change in the circuit?

Would the performance of the capacitor change in any significant or measurable way?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/280719/how-to-derate-a-ceramic-capacitor-for-dc-bias
Yes, the voltage rating can affect how the capacitor behaves under a dc bias, but it probably wont matter a huge amount for most circuits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With high value ceramics like that, a higher specified voltage will mean a higher capacitance at your operating voltage. That is, the capacitor won't lose as much of its zero volts rated capacitance to voltage coefficient.

In decoupling applications, a little extra capacitance is a good thing. Given the tolerance of these capacitors, it's unlikely the circuit has been designed to rely on a particular reduced value.

Comment: My experience with high value ceramics in small packages has not been as you describe. A higher specified voltage rating does not dictate its capacitance under DC bias. It only dictates the range of safe voltages that can be applied. In many cases, higher-V-rated caps have shown similar or worse Capacitance vs. Voltage performance. I've used the manufacturers' tools (e.g. Murata Simsurfing) to demonstrate this in the past.

Comment: Agree with Kevin. It's more of a physical size (including z hight) for a given capacitance and high k material.